# UITextFieldDelegate extension function does not triggers, why?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, protocols

I have `SequencedTextFields` protocol, which contains sequence of text fields. When user taps `Return` button on keyboard, current text field should resign first responder and next text field in the sequence should become first responder. And it works good, when I'm using direct implementation of `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol for view controller:

```
extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        nextInSequence(after: textField)?.becomeFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

But, when I'm trying to use `default` implementation, it does not triggers ever:

```
extension UITextFieldDelegate where Self: SequencedTextFields {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        nextInSequence(after: textField)?.becomeFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

What could be the reason? Or I've missed something?

UPDATE:

My view controller defining:

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, SequencedTextFields
```

Setting up the delegate for the text fields:
[image]

Comment: Are you setting the delegate properly?

Comment: @Nullify yes, it works, when I'm using first example of code

Comment: show me where you are setting your text field delegate to self? use your textfield.delegate = self as? SequencedTextFields

Comment: @Nullify I did it in the storyboard

Comment: @Nullify added screenshot

Comment: use code to set it. remove the storyboard delegate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157817/discussion-between-vasilii-muravev-and-nullify).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your implementation is not working is because you are trying to extend an interface (`UITextFieldDelegate`) instead of a class, that's why it works when you use `UIViewController` instead.

What you can do is to **create a custom class** `SequencedTextField` that extends `UITextField`. Add a custom delegate (that I called `sequencedDelegate` that represents the class that implements your `SequencedTextFields` protocol.

**Extend** `SequencedTextField` to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` with your default implementation.

On `MyViewController`, set up your `SequencedTextField` delegate with the `viewController` itself.

At the end it should look something like this:

```
protocol SequencedTextFields: class {
    func nextInSequence(after: UITextField) -> UITextField?
}

class SequencedTextField: UITextField {
    weak var sequencedDelegate: SequencedTextFields?
}

extension SequencedTextField: UITextFieldDelegate {
    public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        sequencedDelegate?.nextInSequence(after: textField)?.becomeFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController, SequencedTextFields {
    var textField = SequencedTextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = textField
        textField.sequencedDelegate = self
    }

    func nextInSequence(after: UITextField) -> UITextField? {
        // your view controllers nextInSequence implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated answer!

Comment: `UITextFieldDelegate` is a public protocol. Swift allows extending protocol, so weird that it isn't works. For example I have "extension SequencedTextFields where Self: UIViewController" (with "func nextInSequence(after textField: UITextField) -> UITextField?") which works as expected.

Comment: You can obviously extend a protocol, but you can't implement a protocol function inside the protocol extension itself. Thats why when you extend `UITextFieldDelegate` the trigger doesn't work. Your `SequencedTextFields` works because you extend the protocol alone and you implement it on the UIViewController. The correct way to implement what you want is creating your custom `UITextField` or a custom class that implements `UITextViewDelegate` as you want, and then use an instance of that class as delegate in every controller that you need the standard functionality.

Comment: Check apple documentation: ```You can use protocol extensions to provide a default implementation to any method or computed property requirement of that protocol. If a conforming type provides its own implementation of a required method or property, that implementation will be used instead of the one provided by the extension.``` - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Answer (score 0):

**What is wrong with your code?**

The first extension is the extension of your view controller `MyViewController`, that's why it is working. But the second one is the extension of `UITextFieldDelegate`. Those are completely two different things.

Not clear what you want to achieve.

**This is how you can use your custom protocol**

If you want to make one CustomProtocol for your special UITextField you can do like this.

**CustomTextFieldProtocol**

- Declear the protocol

  ```
  protocol SequencedTextFields: UITextFieldDelegate {
      func checkSomeThing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
  }
  ```
- Set the delegate

  ```
  self.textField.delegate = self
  ```
- ViewController Extension to implement your Delegate methods

  ```
  extension ViewController: SequencedTextFields {

      func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
          textField.resignFirstResponder()
          nextInSequence(after: textField)?.becomeFirstResponder()
          return true
      }

      func checkSomeThing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
          print("Check here")
          return true
      }
  }
  ```